# Can't delete AWS backup plan as root user

Tags: amazon-web-services

I wanted to delete an AWS backup plan through the console and I get an Access Denied error when logged on as a user with full administrator access.

Even when I log on as a root user I get an Access Denied error.

When looking in cloudtrail: the errorCode=AccessDenied, and the errorMessage="An unknown error occurred"

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you definitely have full admin? Is a resource policy blocking you instead? Are there any outages listed on the AWS status pages?

Comment: Are there any service control policies in place that might prevent this?